# Multiplying two columns and display result in third column in java gui form

Tags: java, netbeans-8, master-detail

I have made a master detail form in Java in netbeans 8.2. In detail form along with other columns I have price, quantity and Total Amount columns. Now I want that when I enter the price and quantity it automatically calculates the total Amount.I have tried some methods but they do not work.
How can I do that ?
Thanks for helping.

The code for the amount column is as following:

public BigDecimal getAmt() {

```
    try{
    BigDecimal bg1 = new BigDecimal("qty");
    BigDecimal bg2 = new BigDecimal("rate");
    BigDecimal result = bg1.multiply(bg2);
    amt = result;
      return amt;
    }catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
    return amt;
}

public void setAmt(BigDecimal amt) {
    BigDecimal oldAmt = this.amt;
    this.amt = amt;
    changeSupport.firePropertyChange("amt", oldAmt, amt);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **KeyListener** interface for these type of events.
You can perform event on both columns price and quantity.
use below link for your reference[1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) :

Comment: Thanks for your answer but can you tell me that how can I do this? I am new to java.